# Terraform - Doesn't show which resource is producing error

Tags: terraform

For some reason `Terraform` doesn't show which resource is producing error. It just outputs the errors. Is there a way I can make sure terraform shows which resource is producing the error?

I'm using `Terraform v0.12.21`.
`Terraform plan` doesn't produce any errors. The error is during the `apply` command.

All the resources are in different `tf` files and I have to go through one by one to figure out which wasn't run and producing error.

In the below error, lb_listener has completed. So I'm not which was next that could be producing the error.

```
module.Tester_vpc.aws_lb_target_group.nlb_tg_port_80[0]: Creating...
module.Tester_vpc.aws_lb_target_group.nlb_tg_port_80[0]: Creation complete after 1s [id=arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-south-1:123456:targetgroup/nlbPort80/123456]
module.Tester_vpc.aws_lb_listener.listener[0]: Creating...
module.Tester_vpc.aws_lb_listener.listener[0]: Creation complete after 1s [id=arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-south-1:123456:listener/net/myNLB/123456/8d51be081230319c]

Error: no matching SecurityGroup found



Error: Your query returned no results. Please change your search criteria and try again.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, I'm fairly sure it's not a resource failing that is causing the error.

`Error: Your query returned no results. Please change your search criteria and try again.`

This is the error message that a data source gives when it fails. Do you have an [`aws_security_group`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/security_group) data source that's failing?

As to your actual question, how to troubleshoot these sorts of errors. I always reach for `TF_LOG` (see https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/debugging.html).

You can set `TF_LOG` as an environment variable with the value `DEBUG` (or `TRACE`) to see detailed debugging information. Often this will include the output of what fails.

Here's an example:

```
$ TF_LOG=DEBUG terraform apply
```

Comment: In my case, I used `TF_LOG=ERROR` to reduce the number of log entries.